# Is the paging area on a hard disk in a specific location or are the data blocks also distributed over the entire hard disk?

Tags: process, operating-system, paging, virtual-memory, hard-drive

I was wondering if the paging area is on a hard disk in a specific location or are the data blocks also distributed over the entire hard disk?

And beyond: When a process is loaded that consists of my code and the data, only part of the code is loaded into the RAM based on the prepaging and the rest is loaded onto the hard drive or everything is completely stored in the RAM at first?

Is it possible that processes with the status “ready”, i.e. those that may be due soon, also completely swapped out in the background memory?

Answer (score 1):

The overall answer is *depends upon your system*.

Over history, some systems have required dedicated discs or drums for swap area, some dedicated partitions, and later files which may be dynamically added and removed.  Dedicated swap areas have some latency, performance and simplicity advantages over file-based swap; however the latter is far more flexible.

Theoretically, none of the code or data needs to be loaded.  All that it needs is  a set of page tables associated to offsets within the executable file.  In practice, some of these pages are referenced to get load module headers and dependencies upon shared objects, so there is no advantage to not leaving them around.  Have a careful read of mmap(2), it is the workhorse of this.

The scheduling of the cpu doesn't need to know anything about the status of the memory pages in the executable; so in theory yes.  In practice, it is unlikely.  Either way, the attempt to run it would cause its pages to be brought back.

btw, background memory is more likely *backing store*, which identifies where the page either exists (not in ram), or will be stored if evicted from ram.